# .htaccess rewrite urls with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite my urls through a .htaccess file to make them more clean looking. I have

```
http://localhost:801/Test/test.php?school=19&name=Greenhaven-Elementary
```

and it needs to end up looking like

```
http://localhost:801/Test/test.php/19/Greenhaven-Elementary
```

In my .htaccess file I have the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/+]+)([0-9]+)$ test.php?school=/$1&name=$2/ [L]
```

I have tried other ways but being new at using .htaccess files I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're after:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} school=(.+)&name=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/Test/test.php/%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

**So what does the above do?**

First, it will take the query `school=` and `name=` as a condition, if this condition is met then it will grab any version of the variables using `(.+)`.

It will then rewrite the URL using 301 redirection to show http://localhost:801/Test/test.php/anything/anything2. The use of `%1` and `%2` is to grab the variables from `school=` / `name=` and then we use `?` to stop the original query string from appearing on the end of the newly rewritten URL.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

**EDIT:**

I wrote this for the singular query:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} item=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/Test/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

This includes removing `test.php` and on my server works without issue and returns http://localhost:801/Test/anything

Comment: How would that transfer over to only one parameter? example being i have an additional url http://localhost:801/Test/test.php?item=82 but when I change the .htaccess                                                     RewriteEngine On
RewiteCond %{QUERY_STRING} item=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/Test/test.php/%1? [R=301,NC,L]   I get an error

Comment: Also is there a way to get the test.php to not show up in the completed url?

Comment: @StevenLarson It errors because you didn't include `http://` before the localhost bit :) - yes, the test.php can be removed. You just need to take it out from the RewriteRule. So: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/test/%1? [R=301,NC,L]` - If the question helped you, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: yes I had tried taking out the test.php and ended with this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/Test/%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]` but it will now return a 404 error... Also when I try with the one variable I get a 500 server error. My line looks like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:801/Test/test.php/%1? [R=301,NC,L]`